# using the Color datatype in unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to change the colour of the object at the start of the game, however nothing happens i run the program. the program works when i use `Player.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red` ,but i dont want to rewrite that line everytime i want to change the colour.

```
    public GameObject Player;
    private Color Plcol;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Plcol = Player.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
        Plcol = Color.red;
    }
```

Comment: Make a function called SetPlayerColor and put the line you don't want to retype in it. Your code is now cleaner and more self documenting.

Comment: You are just replacing the field value of `Plcol` ... this will not change the `material.color` ... it's the same if you say e.g. `var x = transform.position.x; x = 5;` ... why should this change the `transform.position` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning a color to the variable and then changing it, since the material color is using PInvoke (call to C++) you need to do the direct assignment.

```
public GameObject Player;

void Start()
{
    ChangeColor(Color.red);
}

public void ChangeColor(Color newColor)
{
    Player.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = newColor;
    //or should work as well
    var material = Player.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    material.color = newColor;
}
```